# How large can a circle's radius be in an ellipse?

Tags: circles, conic-sections

I have an ellipse centered on the origin parameterized by $a$ and $b$. Given its $x$ coordinate, how large can its radius be and still have the circle inside the ellipse?

Comment: The largest possible radius is the distance from the circle's center, $(x,0)$ to the ellipse. Equivalently, it's the minimum distance from $(x,0)$ to an arbitrary point $P$ in the plane, subject to the constraint that the point is on the ellipse. Lagrange multipliers might be a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

The maximal radius is the minor axis of the ellipse. You can derive this by first picking the $x$ coordinate, then optimizing.

Comment: This is incorrect because if the circle were further over, a circle with that radius would extend beyond the ellipse

Comment: The circle centered at $(x,0)$ can only have radius equal to the minor axis of the ellipse if $x=0$. For any other $x$-value, the circle's maximum radius is smaller.